# Multiple classitems in a mapfile

Tags: mapserver, symbology, mapfile

I would like to get a symbology using several columns. I have read that it was not possible to set up several fields within the CLASSITEM option in the mapfile. I have tried to do this in a different way but the layer is not displaying at all...

I'm using Mapserver 6.2.1. Here is a simplified extract of my mapfile's code :

```
CLASS
  NAME "Symbol 1"
  EXPRESSION (("[field1]"="01") && ("[field2]"="01"))
  STYLE
    SYMBOL circle
    COLOR 255 0 0
    SIZE 10
  END
END

CLASS
  NAME "Symbol 2"
  EXPRESSION (("[field1]"="02") && ("[field2]"="02"))
  STYLE
    SYMBOL circle
    COLOR 0 255 0
    SIZE 10
  END
END
```

Comment: Columns "field1" and "field2" are both strings, or what?

Comment: Absolutely ! I had checked it out before posting.

Comment: The syntax of expressions is mystique but I have learned that almost everything is possible after rather a lot trial and error struggle. Try something like `EXPRESSION ('[field1]'='02' AND '[field2]'='02')`.

Comment: Just tried these (without success) : 
    EXPRESSION ('[field1]'='02' AND '[field2]'='02')EXPRESSION ("[field1]"="02" AND "[field2]"="02")  
  
    EXPRESSION ('[field1]'='02') AND ('[field2]'='02')  
    EXPRESSION ("[field1]"="02") AND ("[field2]"="02")  
  
    EXPRESSION (('[field1]'='02') AND ('[field2]'='02'))  
    EXPRESSION (("[field1]"="02") AND ("[field2]"="02"))  
  
    EXPRESSION ("[field1]"='02' AND "[field2]"='02')  
    EXPRESSION (("[field1]"='02') AND ("[field2]"='02'))  
  
Just can't find out what is wrong...

Comment: Which MapServer version, Windows or Linux? PostGIS or shapefile source or something else?

Comment: Mapserver 6.2.1 - Windows 7 Professional - PostGIS 2.0.1 (PostgreSQL 9.2.2)

Comment: I can only say that with Mapserver 6.4 on Windows 7 and shapefile as source this works: CLASS NAME "OK" 
      EXPRESSION ('[field1]'='OK' AND '[field2]'='not_OK'). But well, perhaps leading zeroes makes trouble once again. Edit your data to use "p02" and make a new test.

Comment: Still not good for me... Anybody with PostGIS as a source ?

Comment: Make it easier for others, take your data from PostGIS into shapefile and test if it works in the same way than for me. If yes, you know it has to do with PostGIS, if not, we have still different MapServer versions. V. 6.2 is not maintained and thus it would be best to update to 6.4 or 6.5-dev but unfortunately on Windows is not totally trivial.

Comment: I have identified the issue : I have 3 expressions. Two are on varchar columns (no problem with them) and the third one is on a double precision column. I write :    EXPRESSION ("[field3]" >= 60) and this disables the display of the layer... How to write this expression ?

Comment: Well... field3 is indeed double precision. If I write     EXPRESSION ("[field3]" = "60"), it works... But    EXPRESSION ("[field3]" > "60") doesn't, nor EXPRESSION ("[field3]" > 60). What a mess !

Comment: For numbers I use syntax `EXPRESSION ([field1]>10)`. Yes, it is a mess.

Comment: ... and that's it ! Yeaaah ! Urah ! I had just found it and was getting ready to post it. How can I mark your comment as the good answer to my topic ?

Comment: I converted it into an answer. I hope it suits with your observations but comment the answer if is doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions in MapServer are rather messy from users point of view even the documentation at http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html may feel fine for MapServer developers.

What user must know is that datatypes matter and syntax is different for numbers and strings. For strings both the attribute name and its value must be quoted

```
EXPRESSION ('[field1]'='02')
```

For numbers syntax is without quotation

```
EXPRESSION ([field1]=02)
```

Expression that combines one string and one numeric field comes as

```
EXPRESSION ('[field1]'='02' AND [field2]>60)
```

Using wrong syntax may give correct result sometimes which is even more baffling for users. For a numeric attribute syntax `("[field3]" = "60")` finds correct features because number "60" is found also with string comparison. However, string comparison `("[field3]" > "60")` may not give desired result because "is lexicographically larger" is a fuzzy by definition and "7" is probably larger than "60".